Flutter stripe web integration
I have used following method for stripe payment.
Stripe.instance.dangerouslyUpdateCardDetails(
CardDetails(
number: '4242424242424242',
cvc: '314',
expirationMonth: 05,
expirationYear: 29,
),
);

while calling this method in web getting following error.
WebUnsupportedError: dangerouslyUpdateCardDetails is not supported for Web.

Can any one have idea or solution for working this in web?
I am using following package with version:
flutter_stripe: ^10.1.1
flutter_stripe_web: ^5.1.0
Please help me I spend a week for it to working out.
Is there any other way to use custom cardDetail UI(card_number, card_name, expiry, cvv) for generating card payment method?
